# Silverlight 4 Custom login

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, authentication

I'm having a user class which has a many to one relationship with an usertype class. A usertype class has all sorts of permissions.

What would be the best approach for me to work with a custom login/role system in silverlight 4?

Comment: When you say "best approach" are you talking about database table design or the application framework?

Comment: Also, can the permissions on the usertype class be modified or are they static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting In-Browser only ,and the ASP.Membership services is the provider use normal ASP.Net page itself.It can be styled to look like your Silverlight app. Once the login is successful you may redirect to the wen page which hosts the Silverlight content.

The screens in Silverlight application can be shown per user type if you have a service which returns the user type.